# moodle api with soap and coldfusion cfhttp service

Tags: php, soap, coldfusion, moodle, cfc

I am trying to moodle api to build in coldfusion but i am confused about few things

First point, I am using the soap option to make a call to the server with the following code:

```
$functionname = 'core_user_create_users';
$user1 = new stdClass();
$user1->username = 'abcd';
$user1->password =  'Password123!';
$user1->firstname = 'ali';
$user1->lastname = 'asdsad';
$user1->email = 'asd@asd.com';
$user1->city = 'apo';
$user1->country = 'addfa';
$user1->auth = 'manual';
$params = array($user1);

// SOAP CALL
$serverurl = 'http://your_install.com/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl=1&wstoken=your_token';
///Do the main soap call
$client = new SoapClient($serverurl);
try {
  $resp = $client->__soapCall($functionname, array($params));
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
  exit($e->faultstring);
}
```

I have few doubts:

1. it uses `$user1 = new stdClass();` - i could not it anywhere else in the code, is it somethimg like `structnew` in coldfusion
2. the way it makes soap call, i am lost

i have my coldfusion code as below

```
<cffunction access="remote" name="core_user_create_users" returntype="any" returnformat="json" hint="Create Users for Moodle">
    <cfargument name="structform" default="" type="struct">
    <cfset var getMoodleToken = getTokenFromMoodle()>
    <cfset var createURL = getDomainName()>
    <cfset var services = "/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl=1&wstoken=" & getMoodleToken>
    <cfhttp url="#createURL##services#" method="get">
</cffunction>
```

but after the `cfhttp` call i am not sure what to do and pass, please guide

Update#1

Making a call like this now and getting this error

```
<cffunction access="remote" name="getAllFunctions" returntype="any" returnformat="json" hint="Get all avaliable Functions from Moodle">
    <cfset var getMoodleToken = getExternalTokenFromMoodle()>
    <cfset var createURL = getDomainName()>
    <cfset var services = createURL & "/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl=1&wstoken=" & getMoodleToken>
    <cfset obj = createobject("webservice",services)>
    <cfreturn obj>
</cffunction>

<cffunction access="remote" name="createUser" returntype="any" returnformat="json" hint="Create Users for Moodle">
    <cfargument name="structform" default="" type="struct">
    <cfset obj = getAllFunctions()>
    <cfset var user = structnew()>
    <cfset user.username = arguments.structform.username>
    <cfset user.password = arguments.structform.password>
    <cfset user.firstname = arguments.structform.firstname>
    <cfset user.lastname = arguments.structform.lastname>
    <cfset user.email = arguments.structform.email>
    <cfset user.auth = arguments.structform.auth>
    <cfset user.idnumber = arguments.structform.idnumber>
    <cfset user.lang = arguments.structform.lang>
    <cfset user.theme = arguments.structform.theme>
    <cfset user.timezone = arguments.structform.timezone>
    <cfset user.mailformat = arguments.structform.mailformat>
    <cfset user.description = arguments.structform.description>
    <cfset user.city = arguments.structform.city>
    <cfset user.country = arguments.structform.country>
    <cfset objResults = obj.core_user_create_users(user)>
    <cfdump var="#objResults#">
</cffunction>

Unable to create web service argument class [Ljava.lang.Object;. Error: java.lang.InstantiationException: [Ljava.lang.Object;. Often this is because the web service defines an abstract complexType as an input to an operation. You must create an actual instance of this type in Java.
Message     Error converting CFML arguments to Java classes for web service invocation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - this will be complex trial and error to get this working. Expect to have to work through one step then on to the next error before you are successful.

So I have one clue for you - assuming the cfhttp call returns a WSDL of some sort, you should be able to use a component call. Try this:

```
<cffunction access="remote" name="core_user_create_users" returntype="any" returnformat="json" hint="Create Users for Moodle">
    <cfargument name="structform" default="" type="struct">
    <cfset var getMoodleToken = getTokenFromMoodle()>
    <cfset var createURL = getDomainName()>
    <cfset var services = "/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl=1&wstoken=" & getMoodleToken>

    <cfset obj = createobject("webservice",services)>
    <cfdump var="#obj#">

</cffunction>
```

The WSDL should be compiled into a stub class with members (functions and properties). One of them is going to be `core_user_create_users()` and it will take an array objects. The tricky part will be figuring out how to format that array to pass it correctly. If you are luck a CF array of objects ([1]["username:abc"]) might serialize correctly. If not you will have to trial and error your way through it till you figure it out. good luck John!

Comment: ok, Thanks, It gives me after i make a dump to the files `core_user_create_users(java.lang.Object[])  java.lang.Object[]
core_user_delete_users(java.lang.Object[])  void`

Comment: Good! progress :)   ... You might try creating a structure (user.username = 'blah", user.password = 'blah') and then passing it in as obj.core_user_create_user(user).... it's just crazy enough to work. :) But the soap object might require something else - a vector or object signature that is not presented by the struct - in which case you have to fiddle with java or javacast to get it  right.

Comment: Yep - this is the next stage. Does your service have a Java example? That might be useful. You will probably need to use createobject to create a certain kind of Java class and then populate it, then pass that to your service. Examining the WSDL xml might give you some clues as well. Welcome to the trial and error of SOAP services. :)

Comment: check this link `https://github.com/moodlehq/sample-ws-clients`, it uses java and php but there is no SOAP for JAVA Example. That is all what i could find